# Get sequences of same values within list and count elements within sequences

Tags: python

I'd like to find the amount of values within **sequences** of the same value from a list:

```
list = ['A','A','A','B','B','C','A','A']
```

The result should look like:

```
result_dic = {A: [3,2], B: [2], C: [1]}
```

I do not just want the counts of different values in a list as you can see in the result for A.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that, he's looking for specifically when a duplicate comes after each other unbroken by non duplicates. I'd suggest a [DefaultDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

listy = ['A','A','A','B','B','C','A','A']

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in groupby(listy):
  d[k].append(len([*v]))

d

defaultdict(list, {'A': [3, 2], 'B': [2], 'C': [1]})
```

---

- `groupby` will loop through an iterable and lump contiguous things together.

  ```
  [(k, [*v]) for k, v in groupby(listy)]

  [('A', ['A', 'A', 'A']), ('B', ['B', 'B']), ('C', ['C']), ('A', ['A', 'A'])]
  ```
- So I loop through those results and append the length of each grouped thing to the values of a `defaultdict`

Comment: I like that you used `groupby`, better and more readable than my approach.

Comment: Thanks @Jaba.  However, some people like to see the logic laid out.  Your answer is a good one as well.

Comment: Alternative (to avoid intermediary lists that are then discarded): instead of `len([*v])` you can use `sum(1 for _ in v)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and looping through the list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

sample = ['A','A','A','B','B','C','A','A']

result_dic = defaultdict(list)
last_letter = None
num = 0

for l in sample:
    if last_letter == l or last_letter is None:
        num += 1
    else:
        result_dic[last_letter].append(num)
```

**Edit**
This is my approach, although I'd have a look at @piRSquared's answer because they were keen enough to include `groupby` as well. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looping through the list.

```
result_dic = {}
old_word = ''

for word in list:
    if not word in result_dic:
        d[word] = [1]
    elif word == old_word:
        result_dic[word][-1] += 1
    else:
        result_dic[word].append(1)
    old_word = word
```

Comment: Please explain your approach when answering, don't just put code in. This is lazy and doesn't do much for the OP

Comment: I'm not lazy, never have been. But I don't see the point of describing such a simple code snippet.  Especially with such a verbose language as python.  It's like writing the same code twice but in different language.  Don't see the point of people having to read the same thing twice.  Rest assured if I post something more complicated I will add ample explanations.

Comment: I did not say you were lazy, what I meant was that if someone is asking as "simple" a question as this, then some explanation as to what your code does is much more helpful for them than just a code snippet, also it's a part of [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Again, you aren't wrong, just not as helpful when answering only code.